# C++ Windows.h WriteConsoleCharacter crashes for large arrays

Tags: c++, windows

I created Conway's game of life in C++ using the console to display graphics. It's been working fine for resizing everything but when I put in large input the console window opened up for a second an closed. The window is resizing but WriteConsoleOutputCharacter causes the console to close out and sometimes the process keeps running but the window disappears.

This is the code I have:

```
HANDLE outHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
HANDLE inHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

CreateConsole(WIDTH, HEIGHT, TEXT_SIZE, TEXT_SIZE, outHandle, inHandle, "Game of Life");
char* screen = new char[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
for (int r = 0; r < HEIGHT; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < WIDTH; c++)
    {
        if (r != 0 && c != 0 && r != HEIGHT - 1 && c != WIDTH - 1)
            screen[r * WIDTH + c] = rand() % 3 == 1 ? 219 : ' ';
        else
            screen[r * WIDTH + c] = ' ';
    }
}

DWORD numCharsWritten;
WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(outHandle, screen, WIDTH * HEIGHT, { 0, 0 }, &numCharsWritten);
```

This is the CreateConsole function but I don't think it's the problem:

```
if (title.length())
    SetConsoleTitle(title.c_str());

SMALL_RECT windowSize = { 0, 0, static_cast<short>(screenW - 1), static_cast<short>(screenH - 1) };
SMALL_RECT rectWindow = { 0, 0, 1, 1 };
COORD bufferSize = { static_cast<short>(screenW), static_cast<short>(screenH) };

SetConsoleWindowInfo(outHandle, true, &rectWindow);

if (!SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(outHandle, bufferSize))
{
    std::cout << "Buffer Not Set" << std::endl;
    return;
}
if (!SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(outHandle))
{
    std::cout << "Buffer Not Assigned" << std::endl;
    return;
}

CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi;
cfi.cbSize = sizeof(cfi);
cfi.nFont = 0;
cfi.dwFontSize.X = fontW;
cfi.dwFontSize.Y = fontH;
cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;

if (!SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(outHandle, false, &cfi))
{
    std::cout << "Font Could Not Be Set" << std::endl;
    return;
}

if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(outHandle, true, &windowSize))
{
    std::cout << "Window Size Not Set" << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

When I use numbers like WIDTH=180 HEIGHT=100 TEXT_SIZE=8 the array is displayed and there are no errors. However, when I use something like WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=200 TEXT_SIZE=4 the console closes without warning or displaying an error. I haven't been able to find much online but my guess is that the array is too large for the function so would there be any other ways to do this?

Comment: On a significantly less flippant note, You can probably get more information and narrow down the scope of the problem, maybe even make a [mcve], by stepping through the code with a debugger so you can see exactly what's happening and when.

Comment: Another thing to try is check out some of the return codes from the win32 calls you're making and iff they are reporting errors, check see if any give you [`GetLastError `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) to see why the call didn't work.

Comment: For your `cout` messages to be useful, you need to run your app with a console that's inherited, such as from CMD or PowerShell. Otherwise the console is destroyed when your app exits because no other program is attached to it. That said, it would be even better to log errors to a temp file (e.g. "appname_{PID}.log"), since you're modifying the console itself.

Comment: I updated it to a log file and I was getting ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED which I couldn't figure out. I switched it to use WriteConsoleOutput instead and that works no matter how large of an array I put in it.